# Springer article template package - how to put my emaill address in a paper?

Tags: email

I downloaded:

https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support

And this is how I changed part with authors and emails:

```
\author{\fnm{Myname} \sur{Mysurname}}
\email{myemail@gmail.com}
```

And what I get in PDF then is "contributing authors: myemail@gmail.com". I didn't put there any information that this email is owned by some contributing authors. This template looks like broken in that sense. It shouldn't print anything like that. But how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome! Latex looks to me like really buggy stuff. Isn't it?

Comment: if you are planning to submit the paper you are the contributing author, and the journal will list you as such. That is not a bug.

Comment: There are surely other ways how to handle authors' names and e-mail addresses. But this is how the authors of this document class decided to do. You may want to contact them and suggest how this could be improved. As far as I understand, as soon as you place `\email` after an `\author` command, this e-mail is associated with the author that you defined before. If you omit the `\email` command, the relevant author won't have an e-mail address associated with it. Also, if you use `\author*`, this will be a "corresponding author". If you use `\author`, this will be a "contributing author".